# Invalid Product Key Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, windows-installation

I'm trying to install windows 8 64-bit on my notebook using a genuine windows DVD but right after I select language and click on "install" it says the key is invalid even if it didn't asked me to type any key. But the 32-bit version DVD is working fine (I needed to install it to be able to use the notebook but it's 64-bit processor so I want to install 64-bit version). I also tried get a iso copy from a friend to install from USB device but I got exactly same error. How do I fix it?

Comment: If it is a legal copy of Windows 8 then call Microsoft and have them help you through it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Win8 from ISO image error](http://superuser.com/questions/517185/installing-win8-from-iso-image-error), also [“The product key entered does not match any of the Windows image”](http://superuser.com/questions/643240/the-product-key-entered-does-not-match-any-of-the-windows-image?rq=1)

Comment: Verify the .ISO is for Windows 8 not Windows 8.1 there is a difference.